# Handling 406 http response in angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm using angular with an ngResource factory with a restful controller on a Rails backend. My API responds with a  406 response with a json response structured like the following when a post request is made to create a new record:

```
{ success: false, errors ['error1', 'error2'], message: "record didn't save" }
```

The problem is that I see a post request error in my console when I return the 406 response from the API and angular fails to handle the response.

Something like:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/widget/384/comments 406 (Not Acceptable)    includes.js?v=e777c6e0fdfb9a725e857c8ca3eab18f:545
  sendReplacement includes.js?v=e777c6e0fdfb9a725e857c8ca3eab18f:545
  (anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:8381
  sendReq angular.js?body=1:8181
  $http.serverRequest angular.js?body=1:7922
  wrappedCallback angular.js?body=1:11320
  wrappedCallback angular.js?body=1:11320
  (anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:11406
  Scope.$eval angular.js?body=1:12413
  Scope.$digest angular.js?body=1:12225
  Scope.$apply angular.js?body=1:12517
  (anonymous function) angular.js?body=1:18627
  jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:5117
  elemData.handle
```

My angular code is structured like:

```
Object.save( { object_id: 1 } ).$promise.then(function (response) {
  if (response.success) {
    //success
  } else {
    // something else
  }
```

How do I instruct angular to handle this kind of HTTP response?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your server code in general 406 means that some headers/content type are not acceptable by your client.

Accept: The MIME types accepted by the client. For example, a browser may only accept back types of data (HTML files, GIF files etc.) it knows how to process.
Accept-Charset: The character sets accepted by the client.
Accept-Encoding: The data encoding accepted by the client e.g. the file formats it understands.
Accept-Language: The natural languages (English, German etc.) accepted by the client.
Accept-Ranges: Whether the client accepts ranges of bytes from the resource i.e. a portion of the resource.

So check what headers are being output by your server.

Also you can check what other properties are available on "response" object.